# Find the maximum weight that can be collected from a store under given limit

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I faced this problem in placement exam of SAP labs:

It's your birthday, so you are given a bag with a fixed space '**S**'. You can go to a store and pick as many items you like which can be accommodated inside your bag. The store has '**n**' items and each item occupies a *space* **s[i]**. You have to find out the **maximum space** in bag which you can fill.

For example, say the limit of you bag is *S = 15* and the store has *10* items of sizes *[1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 10, 6, 15, 20, 8]*. Now you can fill *15* space by various ways such as *[1, 7, 3, 4], [7, 3, 5], [15], [5, 10]* and many more. So you return *15*.

**Note:** There is quirk in the sizes of items. All of the items but at most **15** follow the following rule: *for all **i, j,** either **size[i]>=2*size[j]+1** or **size[j] >= 2*size[i] +1** if **i ≠ j**.*

Constraints:

**1<= n <= 60**.

**1<= size[i] <= 10^17**.

**1<= S <= 10^18**.

Example: *S = 9, n = 5, sizes = [1, 7, 4, 4, 10].*

Output: **8**. You can't fill exactly *9* space in any way. You can fill 8 space either by using *[1, 7]* or *[4, 4]*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I tried to solve this problem with the help of backtracking ignoring the information given in note. My solution ran correctly for s0me cases but gave TLE for a lot of cases.

Comment: Did you memorize your solution? there is a DP solution to this in quadratic time

Comment: @thebenman this problem is different from knapsack as it doesn't ask for maximizing no. of items as in knapsack problem. Also the point given in note makes this problem lot more difficult.

Comment: @thebenman Now that you pointed out, I think this problem could've been solved by DP. Feeling sorry for myself :(.

Comment: Happens. Don't worry. Keep practising

Comment: @prakasht no, standard knapsack dp doesnt work because S is too big

Comment: @thebenman added answer if you are interested

Comment: Classic knapsack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let´s call x the elements that follow that rule. Note that for this set of elements, we have some nice properties:

- Given x in sorted ascending order, sum(x[i..j]) < x[j + 1]
- To solve maximum sum <= k, just iterate in sorted descending order and substract from k x[i] whenever possible. original k - remaining k is the solution. Assuming elements were already sorted, this is O(|x|).

One way to obtain this set is to iterate items sorted by size in ascending order and add to set if :

- set has no elements or
- current element >= 2 * size[lastElementAdded] + 1

Now we are left with at most 15 items that do not follow this rule. So we can´t use the efficient solving like before. For each item, we can consider to put it or not in the bag. This leads to 2^15 possible sums. For each of those sums, we can run our method for the elements that follow the rule.

Overall complexity: 2^15 * (n - 15). For n = 60, this should be solved in less than a second.

As an exercise: by using accumulated sums and binary search, it can be brought down to 2^15 * log2(n - 15).

Comment: Nice answer, please also tell how to separate the items which follow the rule from the items which don't.

Comment: @prakasht added :)

Comment: I tried to apply the formula "current element >= 2 * size[lastElementAdded] + 1" but I can't find a way to add first element in the set of x. Please help me with that.

Comment: @prakasht not sure what you mean, first element is always the item with lowest size

Comment: ok my bad, once I tried to run through an example, I understood that first element will always be the item with lowest size. Thanks for the clarification though, I'm just a beginner :p.